# Why is the power of light different at 45 degrees than at 135 degrees of the half wave plate

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, polarization

I have tried to make a polarizing attenuator by using a vertically polarized laser shining light first on a half wave plate that is under an angle *a* opposed to the vertically polarized light. Then the light goes through a polarizing cube where then the power of the transmitted beam is measured with a thorlabs power meter. Now my discoveries were that the power at 45 degrees of *a* is significantly lower than when *a* is 135 degrees, 0.292 mW vs 0.530 mW. I have looked at a lot of possibilities and I think it has something to do with that the light is already polarized, but I really can't figure it out. If anybody could help me that would be lovely.A graph with black dots

Comment: Measure the power vs $\alpha$ and plot it. Include it in your post.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the following:

1. Is the laser polarization really linear and vertical? The easiest way to find this out is to remove the half-wave plate and send the beam directly to the polarizing beamsplitter. If you get close to 100% transmission when the polarizer is vertical, the laser behaves as you expect. If the maximum transmission is clearly less than 100%, the laser light is not linearly polarized, but elliptically.
2. Is the waveplate specified for the wavelength of the laser? If you look through the [Thorlabs catalog](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=711), there is usually a wavelength (range) specified for the waveplates. The reason is that the optical path difference of the *o*- and *e*-polarized part of the beam must be $\lambda/2$. You can imagine that the same waveplate cannot fulfill this condition for all $\lambda$.

   If the waveplate is specified for a different wavelength than the laser, the modulation of the power at the powermeter has a reduced amplitude. You should still be able to reach 100% transmission through the polarizing beamsplitter when the fast or slow axis of the waveplate is aligned with the laser polarization, but the minima expected at angles $a = 45°$ and $a = 135°$ do not rotate the beam polarization by $90°$. Instead, the resulting polarization will be elliptical.

Comment: the light has wavelength 650 mm, but I can't find any specifics in the thorlabs thing as I don't know what the meter is exactly anymore.

Comment: @DayTimeGamer I added a paragraph on how you could check if the waveplate is suited for the laser wavelength.

Comment: From what I understand, the amplitude would just be reduced, it doesn't necessarily explain the huge difference in amplitude between 45 and 135 degrees (which are actually maxima in this case)

Comment: @DayTimeGamer Could you maybe show us the full curve of power vs. angle $a$?